# Create slideshow from images on linux

Tags: php, javascript, video, slideshow

I need to dynamically create a simple but nice slideshow from images on my linux server (CentOs). I'm using `php` with the `dvd-slideshow` and `ffmpeg` tools, but dvd-slideshow is very limited:

1) The quality is absolutely too poor: there's definitely too much loss of quality from the `pngs` to the final `vob` file and no parameter seem to help in this.

2) I can't apply the (just 4) effects on just some part of the frame running at the moment.

Example using: `dvd-slideshow -n test_video -H -sharpen -w template1.txt`

I can't find any tool better than this to use to create my slideshow in the whole www. Can you suggest any? I can use whichever alternative can be flow-controlled by `php`:

1) Every command line tool in linux.

2) Libraries/scripts in `python` or `ruby` (but nothing that need Spielberg to be used with).

3) New `canvas` or `js` library running on nodejs technologies.

4) No online service like `flickfusion`...

Can anyone point me to any solution?